# How can i modify the balance of account on Tezos?

Tags: account, sandbox

I'm working on a project with Tezos. I would like to know if we can change the balance of an account. I work with Ubuntu.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "change the balance of an account"? you mean making a transaction to the account?

Comment: when i get balance of an account                                                                                when i do transaction i want to have a large balance of my account because i want to transfer a big amount

Comment: Are using the sandboxed mode (http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/user/sandbox.html) ? If it is the case, you can use the preconfigured accounts which can be listed with `tezos-client list known addresses`.

Comment: Yes i'm using sandboxed mode but i didn't have idea how to modify or to initialize the balance i want to transfer a large balance from bootstrap1 to bootstrap2 i want to get a big balance of bootstrap1 thank you

Answer (score 2):

In sandboxed mode, if you want to change the default parameters (balances, time between blocks, blocks per voting period, …) you can edit the `sandbox-parameters.json` file (located at the root of the repository).